# appending to a file with ofstream

Tags: c++

I have a problem with appending a text to a file. I open an `ofstream` in append mode, still instead of three lines it contains only the last:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file("sample.txt");
    file << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    file.close();

    file.open("sample.txt", ios_base::ate);
    file << "Again hello, world!" << endl;
    file.close();

    file.open("sample.txt", ios_base::ate);
    file << "And once again - hello, world!" << endl;
    file.close();

    string str;
    ifstream ifile("sample.txt");
    while (getline(ifile, str))
        cout << str;
}

// output: And once again - hello, world!
```

So what's the correct `ofstream` constructor for appending to a file?

Comment: It's well described in the [std::ofstream()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) constructor documentation.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I use a very handy function (similar to PHP file_put_contents)

```
// Usage example: filePutContents("./yourfile.txt", "content", true);
void filePutContents(const std::string& name, const std::string& content, bool append = false) {
    std::ofstream outfile;
    if (append)
        outfile.open(name, std::ios_base::app);
    else
        outfile.open(name);
    outfile << content;
}
```

When you need to append something just do:

```
filePutContents("./yourfile.txt","content",true);
```

Using this function you don't need to take care of opening/closing. Altho it should not be used in big loops

Comment: What's the difference between `std::ios_base::app` and `std::io::app`?

Comment: `app` seeks to end before each write, whereas `ate` opens and seeks to end immediately after opening.

Comment: +1 for php reference. PHP may be hated in some places but it has many many useful little functions like this that make the life of a dev easier :)

Answer (score 18):

Use `ios_base::app` instead of `ios_base::ate` as `ios_base::openmode` for `ofstream`'s constructor.